# Caching in Sitecore Mobile SDK for Xamarin

Tags: caching, mobile, xamarin

I'm aware of the caching in Sitecore when using it as a website but how about caching in Sitecore Mobile SDK? Is there a caching to consider when using the service? I'm using the Sitecore Mobile SDK (WebAPI).